# ANOVA : '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, dataframe

I used the function

```
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import MultiComparison
```

The variable ["happiness_score"] is formed of different scores from 1 to 10, like 7.587.

```
mod = MultiComparison(data = my_data["happiness_score"], groups = my_data["continent"]) 
print(mod.allpairtest(testfunc = stats.ttest_ind, method = "bonferroni", alpha = 0.05)[0])
```

Whenever I execute the first line it tells me

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-84bf8a60f49f> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 mod = MultiComparison(data = my_data["happiness_score"], groups = my_data["continent"]) #first data dependent variable and the group indipendent variable
      3 print(mod.allpairtest(testfunc = stats.ttest_ind, method = "bonferroni", alpha = 0.05)[0])

2 frames
<__array_function__ internals> in unique(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    306 
    307     if optional_indices:
--> 308         perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort' if return_index else 'quicksort')
    309         aux = ar[perm]
    310     else:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Show what `MultiComparison` function is doing.

Comment: @MayankPorwal updated

Comment: By any chance does my_data["happiness_score"] include both strings and floats?

Comment: Please give us some data examples and the import statement for `MultiComparison` or the function definition if you wrote it yourself.

Comment: @JoeTodd I used dtypes to describe the columns and it says " happiness_score                float64 "

Comment: @Nyps just added it

Comment: Your issue doesn't have much to do with ANOVA; it's simply that your dataframe column dtype is unexpectedly string, rather than float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're facing the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620068/not-supported-between-instances-of-float-and-str-error-for-tukey-hsd-tes). np.unique is failing because of a combination of floats & strings. The fix is to pass your 'groups' argument as a list:

`mod = MultiComparison(data = my_data["happiness_score"], groups = list(my_data["continent"]))`

Comment: Thank you! Now it works